# Is there any geometric meaning we could attach to the cosine/sine of a vector in the complex plane, $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given a vector in the plane $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the "cosine of this vector" is
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
and the "sine of this vector" is
$$\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}.$$

We can define the sine and cosine of complex numbers via Euler's relation and by power series. However,

> Is there any geometric meaning we could attach to the cosine/sine of a vector in the complex plane?

That is, given $(c,d) \in \mathbb{C}^2,$ would the "cosine of the vector" be
$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 + d^2}}$$
or would it instead be something like
$$\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{|c|^2 + |d|^2}}?$$

Comment: I think it's confusing to refer to $\mathbb C^2$ as "the complex plane", the latter usually just refers to $\mathbb C$.